# How do you make it so that cpack doesn't add required libraries to an RPM?

Tags: cmake, rpm, cpack

I'm trying to convert our build system at work over to cmake and have run into an interesting problem with the RPMs that it generates (via cpack): It automatically adds all of the dependencies that it thinks your RPM has to its list of required libraries.

In general, that's great, but in my case, it's catastrophic. Unfortunately, the development packages that we build end up getting installed with one our home-grown tool that uses rpm to install them in a separate RPM database from the system one. It's stupid, but I can't change it. What this means is that all of the system libraries that any normal library will rely on (like libc or libpthread) aren't in the RPM database that is being used with our development packages. So, if an RPM for one of our development packages lists system libraries as being required, then we can't install it, as rpm will think that they're not installed (since they're listed in the normal database rather than the one that it's being told to use when installing our packages). Our current build stuff handles this just fine, because it doesn't list any system libraries as dependencies in the RPMs, but cpack automatically populates the RPM's list of required libraries and puts the system libraries in there. I need a way to stop it from doing so.

I tried setting `CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_REQUIRES` to `""`, but that has no effect. The RPM cpack generates still ends up with the system libraries listed as being required. All I can think of doing at this point is to copy the RPM cpack generator and hack it up to do what I want and use that instead of the standard one, but I'd prefer to avoid that. Does anyone have any idea how I could get cpack to stop populating the RPM with required libraries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See bottom of

http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html

The autoreqprov Tag — Disable Automatic Dependency Processing

There may be times when RPM's automatic dependency processing is not desired. In these cases, the autoreqprov tag may be used to disable it. This tag takes a yes/no or 0/1 value. For example, to disable automatic dependency processing, the following line may be used:

AutoReqProv: no

**EDIT:**

In order to set this in cmake, you need to do `set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_AUTOREQPROV " no")`. The *extra space seems to be required* in front of (or behind) the no in order for it to work. It seems that the RPM module for cpack has a bug which makes it so that it won't let you set some its variables to anything shorter than 3 characters long.

Comment: That sounds like what I need to set, but the question is how do I do it using cmake and cpack?

Comment: Okay. You're answer didn't give me all of the information I needed, but it was enough to figure out how to solve it, so I updated the answer to include instructions on how to set `AutoReqProv` using cmake.

Comment: This is correct but conflicts with the [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/CPackRPM.html), which wrongly says it can be set to 1 or 0.

Comment: Added an issse re this inconsistency - see https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19244

Answer (score 3):

To add to [Mark Lakata's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14757154/2034366) above, there's a snapshot of the "Maximum RPM" doc

http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html

that also adds:

> The **autoreq** and **autoprov** tags can be used to disable automatic processing of requirements or "provides" only, respectively.

And at least with my version of CPackRPM, there seems to be similar variables you can set e.g.

`set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_AUTOREQ " no")`

to only disable the automatic dependency processing of 'Requires'.