# CMake/CPack: How to avoid adding dependencies to devel packages

Tags: cmake, rpm, cpack, requires, mageia

In my current setup (C++ project under Mageia 5 built using cmake), the cpack commands below cause the construction of RPM packages with dependencies to devel packages which is unnecessary.

The `_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/rpmbuild.out` file contain the following `Requires` section:

```
Requires: devel(libQt5Core(64bit)) devel(libQt5Test(64bit)) 
devel(libQt5Xml(64bit)) devel(libgcc_s(64bit)) 
devel(liblima-common-data(64bit)) devel(liblima-common-datahandler(64bit)) 
devel(liblima-common-factory(64bit)) devel(liblima-common-fsaaccess(64bit)) 
(…)
```

If found nowhere how this list was generated. If I manually run the find-requires script from RPM and other tools, I don't get devel packages.

The CPack commands are:

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "limacommon")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "LIMA Common libraries")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "CEA LIST")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "Gaël de Chalendar <Gael.de-Chalendar@cea.fr>")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/README")
SET(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/COPYING")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "${LIMA_VERSION_MAJOR}")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "${LIMA_VERSION_MINOR}")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "${LIMA_VERSION_RELEASE}")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "Lima-${LIMA_VERSION_MAJOR}.${LIMA_VERSION_MINOR}")
SET(CPACK_NSIS_INSTALL_ROOT "$PROGRAMFILES64")
SET(CPACK_NSIS_MODIFY_PATH "ON")
SET(CPACK_STRIP_FILES "bin/testDict16;bin/testLexicon")
SET(CPACK_SOURCE_STRIP_FILES "")
if ("x$ENV{LIMA_DISABLE_CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS}" STREQUAL "x")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS ON)
endif()
set(CPACK_GENERATOR ${SPECIFIC_SYSTEM_PREFERED_CPACK_GENERATOR})
```

The code is available  [here](https://github.com/aymara/lima/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt).

How to avoid generating these spurious dependencies ?

Note that this question is not a duplicate of "[How do you make it so that cpack doesn't add required libraries to an RPM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658034/how-do-you-make-it-so-that-cpack-doesnt-add-required-libraries-to-an-rpm)" because this question was about voluntarily disabling automatic dependency tracking while mine is about correcting a wrong behaviour while keeping the automatic dependency tracking. BTW, I already found this question and navigated through the links it contains.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make it so that cpack doesn't add required libraries to an RPM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658034/how-do-you-make-it-so-that-cpack-doesnt-add-required-libraries-to-an-rpm)

Comment: No, I don't think this is a duplicate because this question was about voluntarily disabling automatic dependency tracking while mine is about correcting a wrong behaviour while keeping the automatic dependency tracking.
BTW, I already found this question and navigated through the links it contains.

Comment: `correcting a wrong behaviour` - **Why** do you think that "devel" packages are **wrongly** added here? [mcve] would be helpfull. ... Oh, this `If found nowhere ...` paragraph. I have catched its meaning only now...

Comment: Because no executable or library in the generated package depends on any devel package.
I will try to generate a smaller example but that could be not so easy.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem in the meantime?

Comment: @maxime-esa No. And I do not work anymore with rpm based distributions, so I even do not encounter this problem anymore.